# javaOptions for custom test configuration with SBT

Tags: sbt

I'd like to suspend the forked vm and wait for connection from external debugger only when using the `IntegrationDebug` config.

With reference to the 'shared sources' section in http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html, I come up with the following config:

```
import sbt.Keys._

lazy val IntegrationDebug = config("itd") extend (IntegrationTest)

val scalaTestV = "3.0.4"

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .configs(
    IntegrationTest,
    IntegrationDebug
  )
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
    inConfig(IntegrationDebug)(Defaults.testTasks),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % scalaTestV,
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestV,
    ),
    fork in IntegrationTest := true,
    javaOptions in IntegrationDebug += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8123",
  )
```

However, it doesn't work as expected:

```
it:test -> vm not suspended (expected)
itd:test -> vm not suspended (unexpected!!)
```

If I change the scope of the `javaOptions` to `IntegrationTest`, i.e.

```
 ...
 javaOptions in IntegrationTest += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8123",
 ...
```

then

```
it:test -> vm suspended (unexpected!!)
itd:test -> vm suspended (expected)
```

Is there anyway to make it work like:

```
it:test -> vm not suspended
itd:test -> vm suspended
```

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? And how if you did?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I'm not mistaken, I might have found solution for the problem.

Replacing line:

```
    javaOptions in IntegrationDebug += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8123",
```

with

```
  testOptions in IntegrationDebug += Tests.Argument("-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8123")
```

should do the trick (in this case VM suspended only for the `itd:test` command).

I know its been a long time, but someone might find this useful. I had practically the same problem and this is what solved it for me.